# Accessing extensions in generated types with graphql-codegen and react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-query, graphql-codegen

Here's what my returned GQL data looks like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Orders": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  "extensions": {
    "unlimitedTotal": {
      "Orders": 3534
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that the types generated by `graphql-codegen` only include the fields inside `data`. Is there any way to access `extensions`? As you can see, it contains the number of all results, which is needed for pagination (so I'll use it inside `getNextPageParam` like below)

```
const {data} = useInfiniteGetOrdersQuery(
        'offset',
        { limit: 20 },
        { getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.extensions.unlimitedTotal ... }
    );
```

Here's my config:

```
const config: CodegenConfig = {
    schema: '...',
    documents: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
    generates: {
        './src/gql/index.ts': {
            plugins: ['typescript', 'typescript-operations', 'typescript-react-query'],
            config: {
                fetcher: { endpoint: '...' },
                addInfiniteQuery: true,
            },
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

I tried making a custom fetch function which returns

`return { ...json.data, ...json.extensions, };`

but I don't know how to get the type for extensions now.

Any help is appreciated!